# How to get records between two dates in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

All ...

I need to display records that are between the two dates passed in from DateTimePickers.

I am getting records that are NOT in between the dates that I specified from vb.net.

Please go through the code shown below....

Following is the code :

```
Private Sub btn_Show_Inquiry_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Show_Inquiry.Click
    report_viewer_form.Report_viewer_CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
    report_viewer_form.Report_viewer_CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    str1 = "SELECT * FROM Inquiry_Details WHERE Inquiry_Date>=#" & dtp_inq_from.Text & "# AND Inquiry_Date<=#" & dtp_inq_to.Text & "#"

    If dtp_inq_from.Text > dtp_inq_to.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("FROM_DATE Must Be Less Then TO_DATE.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If cn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        cn.Open()
    End If
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(str1, cn)

    report_dataset = New DataSet
    da.Fill(report_dataset, "table2")
    If MsgBox("Do You Want to Print Report ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        report_viewer_form.Show()
        Dim cr As New ReportDocument
        cr = New Inquiry_CrystalReport
        cr.SetDataSource(report_dataset.Tables("table2"))
        report_viewer_form.Report_viewer_CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What database platform? Looks like Access syntax.

Comment: BTW: You have serious SQL Injection security flaws in this code. Why did you use the parameterized SQL on only some of your statements?

Comment: Can you narrow this code down to just the path that it is running and exhibiting the problem. It is hard to wade through all of that. Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to look at the actual query that is being run?

Comment: I have a vb.net form to pass the dates, I have a crystal report to show output on it

Comment: So which version of str1 is getting executed?

Comment: doesn't access support the `BETWEEN` operator?

Comment: Can you step through in the debugger and print what str1 is before you execute it. Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem seems to be in the way you parse passed date parameters to the query and they're probably not in format that Access would recognize as a valid Date type. Try with **`CDate()`** function to let Access parse your input values to its internal date type properly. It will accept any valid `date expression`:

> Any expression that can be interpreted as a date, including date
>   literals, numbers that look like dates, strings that look like dates,
>   and dates returned from functions. A date expression is limited to
>   numbers or strings, in any combination, that can represent a date from
>   January 1, 100 – December 31, 9999.

Your code could thus look like this:

```
str1 = "SELECT * FROM Inquiry_Details WHERE Inquiry_Date>=CDate('" & 
       dtp_inq_from.Text & "') AND Inquiry_Date<=CDate('" & 
       dtp_inq_to.Text & "')"
```

Another function that you might want to try (if `CDate` won't cut it) is **`DateValue()`**:

> The required date argument is normally a string expression
>   representing a date from January 1, 100 through December 31, 9999.
>   However, date can also be any expression that can represent a date, a
>   time, or both a date and time, in that range.

The success of these two functions might also depend on input date formatting and system locale.