# VB.net and Sql : need to Correct this Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I work with this query and I don't get the correct results

My table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuBOM.png

My app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EaQs.png

The user will choose 2 dates, and the result is the sum of shifts in all days between the 2 dates

This is my code:

```
    cn.Open()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = " SELECT SUM(shift1) + SUM(shift2) + SUM(shift3) as shifts 
                        FROM Statistique 
                        where  nom_produit =  '" & ComboBox4.Text & "' 
                        and  P_Date BETWEEN #" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "#  
                        AND #" & DateTimePicker3.Text & "# 
                        group by nom_produit "
    cmd.Connection = cn
    Dim st As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    cn.Close()
    Label36.Text = st
    Label35.Text = st + st / 100 * 20
```

and this query work properly in MS Access 2007:

```sql
SELECT SUM(shift1) + SUM(shift2) + SUM(shift3) AS shifts 
  FROM Statistique
 WHERE nom_produit = 'BAGS  1000x700' 
   AND p_date BETWEEN #10/07/2014# AND #16/07/2014#
 GROUP BY nom_produit
```

and now I want to get it work in my VB.net project.

**Edit :** when i use single quote instead of # i get this error : oledbexception was unhandled :Type de données incompatible dans l'expression du critère.

Comment: Do you have any database connection to MySQL at all? I think, it's a MS Access only question.

Comment: i use MS Access database with vb.net

Comment: Ok, but you state `and this query work properly in MS Access 2007`. And you are using `VB.NET`, so what is your actual problem? Then dont use `'` quotes.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the 2 conditions with date pickers?For testing..

Comment: the query work in MS Access 2007 , but not in VB.net , i get error oledbexception was unhandled :Type de données incompatible dans l'expression du critère.

Comment: yes when i remove DATE PICKER i get exact result

Comment: So you get the same error when using `'` AND `#`?

Comment: no when i use # i get some results but not exact , but when i use ' i get oledbexception was unhandled :Type de données incompatible dans l'expression du critère. @kay Nelson

Comment: Follow this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555324/how-to-get-records-between-two-dates-in-vb-net

Comment: Thank you very much Mr @NeverHopeless and to all who helps me , it Worked when i use CDate() with DateTimePicker , make an comment to make it as answer to this post

Comment: @YassinKhaloufi, upvote the answer in the link that helped you and mark my comment as helpful so it can be of help to the future visitors. Glad to see you have solved it

Comment: Don't mark your question as solved and don't post the solution into the question. You can post the solution as an answer yourself and then accept it. Please make it clearer than what you have as a solution in the question body.

Comment: i can't make your comment helpful or i don't know how :p , make an answer and i will make it as the answer of this post

Comment: i can't @ArtjomB. i have low reputation points , i need at least 15 and i have just 3

Comment: @NeverHopeless Have you seen [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883296/vb-net-and-sql-need-to-correct-this-query?noredirect=1#comment38652952_24883296)?

Comment: @ArtjomB. when i want to make answer to my post : **Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 7/22/2014 5:12:52 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.**

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Solved when i make **CDate() function** with DateTimePicker

Like this **CDate(" & DateTimePicker2.Text & ")**

and make a **single quote ' instead of #**

Thanks to all for the help and specially to @NeverHopeless