# How can i control Font-size of all UI controls of iOS app sussing a UISLIDER?

Tags: ios, uislider, uifont

I am developing an native iOS application in which there is a font-size control page . there i have minimum font-size as 13px and maximum font size as 23px.

If i change the slider value in that page , throughout the app it has to be reflected how can i achieve these? . Please help me .

I know that in android application we can control the font size globally by changing the text- font- size in dimens.xml  which will be present in values folder of respective resolution. 
So we can control application font-size by changing values dynamically in the dimens.xml . 
Android will take care the resolution folder in which the device  the application running . Only work is to provide values for the text-font-size

So in iOS anyway to control the font-size of all UIControls like the above approach.Because i have number of `UIViewcontrller`'s in my iOS app .

I tried changing  for a particular `UIViewController` by connecting all the UIControls to the `IBOutlet` and controlling them as mentioned @Kapil Choubisa answer for this question . Is this a way i have to repeat for number of `UIViewcontrller`'s in my iOS . Or there is any approach i can easily control whole app font size .

Comment: why repeated  downvote ? . Please specify some reason for that .

Comment: I didn't down vote but someone with your rep should know how to ask a proper question. What have you tried? What is your exact issue? Your question shows no effort (hence the down votes).

Comment: Okay will try to change the question and approaches i have tried

Comment: What's the reason for doing this? In iOS7 in the Settings (General > Accessibility > Larger Text) there is a control that does exactly as you described. You'd be better off having your app adjust based on the native setting rather than implement it yourself in your own settings screen.

Comment: This was a exact duplicate of android app already developed . so in android they have designed this feature . so it's a must to develop so only .

Comment: @Vinodh I don't really agree with that logic, you should think of what is going to be most obvious for the user. The experience is different between an iOS and Android app, removing features already built into the OS is probably a better choice.

Comment: Is the feature  available in iOS 6 also . Deployment target is 6.0 so only . Okay i will discuss about this issue .

Comment: @Vinodh That settings screen doesn't exist in iOS 6. The common minimum target for most apps is the last two, so most would be targeting 7 and 8 now, however if you do want iOS 6 then possibly check the OS version at runtime and only show the screen to change the size if the OS version is 6 or below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your font size in some variable. You can save it in `AppDelegate`. Create a property in AppDelegate.h or use NotificationCenter

**You can use Either**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float fontSize;
```

In your font-size control page, in `UISilder`'s value change method assign the float value to the property:

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)slider {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fontSize = // your result font size between 13-23
}
```

In other ViewController's `viewWillAppear` method assign the font to controls

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:appDelegate.fontSize];  
     // If you have different font family for all controls than you have to create different font object and assign but font size can be accessed from appDelegate.fontSize
     yourAllLabels.font = font;
     yourAllTextFields.font = font;
     yourAllButtons.titleLabel.font = font;
}
```

**Or**

In Each ViewController's viewDidLoad method you can register an observer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fontSizeDidChanged:) name:@"fontSizeChanged" object:nil];
}

- (void)fontSizeDidChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
   float fontSize = [[notification object] floatValue];
   UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];  
     yourAllLabels.font = font;
     yourAllTextFields.font = font;
     yourAllButtons.titleLabel.font = font;

}

- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)slider {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fontSizeChanged" object:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:yourFloatFontSize]];
}
```

There are plenty of other ways to store font size or store fonts (if all have same font famitly). You can store font or font size in NSUSerDefaults instead of AppDelegate, it all on you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You  may need some KVO to automatically change the visible fonts on screen as well when the user slides the slider.

Comment: @Milo there is also an option of `NSNotificationCenter` that can be implement as well

Answer (score 0):

Use Singleton design pattern, save this value in a singleton class and access it using its shared instance. Have a look at [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555324/how-to-get-records-between-two-dates-in-vb-net) and see how `someproperty` can be consumed.

Example:

```
//Set
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
sharedManager.someproperty = @"abc";
```

and:

```
//Get
MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];
NSLog(@"%@",sharedManager.someproperty);
```